# Get the sum of multidimensional array on Laravel Collection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

```
$arrays = collect([[0,1], [0,2], [0,3]]);
```

How to get the sum of array?

I tried the code below, but I got error.

```
 return array_map('array_sum', array_map(null, ...collect->toArray());
```

How to achieve this?

```
$arrays = [0,6];
```

Comment: How `[0,5]` is calculated?

Comment: How it is calculated? Explain the algorithm of summation.

Comment: 1 + 2 + 3 = 6 . not 5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sum each element keeping the key

```
    $arrays = collect([[0,1], [0,2], [0,3]]);
    $sum = array_fill(0, count($arrays->first()), 0);
    foreach ($arrays as $collection) {
        foreach ($collection as $key => $value) {
            $sum[$key] += $value;
        }
    }
    dd($sum);
```

this outputs

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => 0
  1 => 6
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Get sum using `Collection`s in Laravel:

```
    $item1_sum = 0;
    $x = collect([[5,1], [0,2], [4,3]])
            ->sum(function($item) use (&$item1_sum) {
                $item1_sum += $item[1];
                return $item[0];
            });
    dd([$x, $item1_sum]); // [9, 6]
```

Comment: [0, 6] because 1 + 2 + 3 = 6